# Bond Price Formula with a Ricatti Equation

Tags: cox-ingersoll-ross

Consider a simplified CIR model given by:

$$ dr = \sqrt(r) dV(t) $$

We have to derive the explicit bond price formulas for this model.

A trick being used with Ricatti equations of form:

$$ B^* = \alpha B^2 + \beta B + \gamma $$

with $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ being constants is to use the following ansatz

$$B = \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{q^*}{q},$$

where this will give a second order ODE for $q$.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried already?